# I keep getting unresolved externals. It's the correct type of project, I have an int main(), nothing seems to be declared within a loop

Tags: c++, external

This is my code so far, split into 3 parts.

http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3686

Here is the error message.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: HW2 - 2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  decoder_prototypes.cpp
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl loadArray(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,int * const)" (?loadArray@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAH@Z) referenced in function _main
>   1>C:\Documents and Settings\Jack\My Documents\School\CS-231\HW 2\HW2 - 2\Debug\HW2 - 2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I see you declare a prototype with this signature:

```
void loadArray (string, int[]);
```

and in source you implement a method with a different signature:

```
void loadArray(long file, int num[])
```

so what happens is that every source file is correctly compiled, as the signature declared in the header file corresponds to the call in your `main` function, but then the function is not found and linking fails.

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I feel really dumb. I confused long doubles for long strings earlier. Durr.

Any idea why it's just a blank screen now?